# Chromium Embedding Framework - обработка сообщений

Tags: c++, google-chrome

Приветствую. Можно ли обрабатывать сообщения CEF отдельной функцией по-одному? Проблема в том, что CEF в моём приложении должен находится в отдельной DLL, поэтому я не могу привязать его к основному циклу обработки сообщений напрямую, однако я мог бы вызывать из того цикла (при каждой итерации) функцию, которая бы обрабатывала сообщений от CEF. Возможно кто-либо уже сталкивался с такой проблемой - отзовитесь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я создал основное окно через Win32, в DLL передал дескриптор и создал контекст браузера (setAsChild) и всё заработало. Браузер был привязан к основному циклу и всё хорошо.